# Using the apex:page action attribute in embedded layouts

Tags: visualforce

Anyone aware of why the initializeActivity method would not be called (when embedded in a layout)?

calling javascript throws a cross domain error. I *really* dont want to have to make a callout to make this work. Im trying to do a dml operation on initializing the controller.

Visualforce:

```
  <apex:page standardController="Contact" 
    extensions="ActivityExtension" action="initializeActivity">
  </apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public ActivityExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
   id = stdController.getId();
   sObjectName = stdController.getRecord().getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
}
public PageReference initializeActivity(){
   read(sObjectName,id);
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oi I feel like an idiot.
Missing the required syntax in the action attribute:

this

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" 
     extensions="ActivityExtension" action="initializeActivity">
</apex:page>
```

should be

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" 
     extensions="ActivityExtension" action="{!initializeActivity}">
</apex:page>
```

nothing to see here...

=)

Comment: Mark the question as answered then :)

Comment: SE makes you wait two days before you can, well, you know.